# Preventing MSAccess linked tables from having a dbo_ prefix?

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to prevent MSAccess from concatenating 'dbo_' as the prefix to tables linked from a SQL Server db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Microsoft Access' native naming convention process will force the name **`<schema>_<ObjectName>`** as your default table name.  There are no controls or settings which will allow you to change that, except in code.  It's rather complex and goes beyond the scope of this question, but if you do the linking in code (which I do) then you can store the TableAlias and create the linked table name that way.

Comment: Thanks. This is suppose to be a "simple" convert from Access ADP to something that Access 2013 can use so I think I will "F2" rename the tables rather then rewrite the linking piece.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your table definition in the code to attach the table as below where
`strTableAlias` is your display name in `Access`
`strTableName` is your table name with schema `<schema>.<ObjectName>`.

```
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(strTableAlias, dbAttachSavePassword, _
 strTableName, strConnectionStr)
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't do the linking in code as mentioned by Johnny you can rename the links with this VBA code:

```
Public Sub Remove_DBO_Prefix()
    Dim obj As AccessObject
    Dim dbs As Object

    Set dbs = Application.CurrentData

    'Search for open AccessObject objects in AllTables collection.
    For Each obj In dbs.AllTables
        'If found, remove prefix
        If Left(obj.Name, 4) = "dbo_" Then
            DoCmd.Rename Mid(obj.Name, 5), acTable, obj.Name
        End If
     Next obj
 End Sub
```

Courtesy https://www.microsoftaccessexpert.com/Microsoft-Access-Code-RemoveDBOPrefix.aspx

If you're doing this with the idea of using queries that you generate in Access outside of Access remember that Access creates it's own sql dialect so you may need to convert double quotes to single and # to ' among other things.

Comment: This script is so helpful but don't know where to place it that we can just use it when needed. Now, I tested by calling the function on form main's loading event

Comment: Add it to a module (not a form) as it's not form specific code. Unless you are linking tables very frequently in a database I'd just run it whenever you add or re-link a SQL Server table. Just use the Immediate Window (View menu) and type Call Remove_DBO_Prefix(), then press Enter.
Otherwise call it via an AutoExec macro.